# dropdown menu - divide sub items by 2 and put them into two column

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have menu, every top has submenu, the count of sub items are not known, I want, if there are, for example, more than 13 items, then, divide them by 2, and put them to a container, as columns, I can do  with css3 column count here , but I need javascript (jQuery) version.

```
      $('.sub-menu').each(function() {
      var count = $(this).find("li").length; 
    if(count >= 12 ){
        $(this).addClass('col2');
    }

   if(count >= 24){
      $(this).toggleClass('col2 col3');
    }
});
```

now I have this,

[image]

I need change it dynamically to this

[image]

here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3KB9j/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tYeDk/97/)**

**css**

```
.dropdown
{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:400;  
    line-height:40px;
    text-indent:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover
{
    background-color:green;
}

.dropdown li ul { 
    display: none; 
    border:black 1px solid;  
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white; 
    width: 150px;    
} 

.dropdown ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


.dropdown a
{
    display:block; 
    padding-right:15px;  
    line-height:30px; 
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown li:hover
{
    background-color:green;
}

.second
{
    left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I need like this, but the .first and .second boxes  must be generated and wrap the sub-items after sub items are over 13, before it they are not wrapped

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/3KB9j/14/

CSS

```
li.col2 { 
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 4px;  
}

.sub-menu.col2 { 
     width: 250%;
 }
```

jquery

```
  $('.sub-menu').each(function () {
      var count = $(this).find("li").length;
      if (count >= 12) {
          $(this).addClass('col2');
          $('li').addClass('col2');
      }

      if (count >= 24) {
          $(this).toggleClass('col2 col3');
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need divide them, and put them into two separate containers, for example the first 9 items, into column1 and the rest ones into column2.

I need this styling them in future

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="width:200px"` to li `.sub-menu` and then Use this:

```
$( ".sub-menu li:odd" ).css( "float", "left" );
$( ".sub-menu li:even" ).css( "float", "right" );
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KB9j/15/)**

Comment: This unfortunately, in its simplicity, uses even and odd to alternate the items when @sarhov needs the first 13 values in the left column and the last values in the right column. Also the width style should be added in CSS, not inline.